# How do I get a FULL build of OpenTK for Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xna, monogame, opentk

I have OpenTK 2.0 installed via NuGet, but it seems that some classes (Point, Rectangle, etc) aren't available in the OpenTK namespace.  I can replace them with System.Drawing.Point and Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle, but then I'm dodging namespace collisions on Vector2 and stuff (OpenTK.* and Microsoft.Xna.Framework.* both include an implementation of Vector2, and Microsoft.Xna.Framework.* and System.Drawing.* contain separate implementations of Rectangle, etc).  Is there a way I can just get the full build of OpenTK and use that to make my namespace less of a mess?

Answer (score 1):

You could build from source manually to get the Rectangle class, but it appears the reason it isn't in the NuGet package is because of some build flags that appear to not be in place for the NuGet build.

From the current develop branch of the project's GitHub repo (https://github.com/opentk/opentk/blob/develop/src/OpenTK/Math/Rectangle.cs, as of 10/3/2016), the entire Rectangle struct is surrounded by a `#if MINIMAL` ... `#endif` directive.  From skimming through the repo, it appears the `MINIMAL` flag prevents some uses of the `System.Drawing` namespace, as well as some other Windows-specific namespaces and classes, though I didn't dig in too deeply.

Would the `Box2` ([GitHub link](https://github.com/opentk/opentk/blob/develop/src/OpenTK/Math/Box2.cs)) or `Box2d` ([GitHub link](https://github.com/opentk/opentk/blob/develop/src/OpenTK/Math/Box2d.cs)) structs suffice for your needs?

Also, for what it's worth, my company has been using OpenTK for one of our major products for some time now, which we would build from source, and OpenTK.Rectangle isn't available in the built 1.1.4 project, either, so this appears to not be a new change.